# Spring '17 bug: SOQL filter on Set with value null now returns nullpointer exception

Tags: apex, soql, spring17

Previously this used to work fine:

```
Set<Id> testSet = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> testSet2 = null;

List<Account> accountList = [Select Id From Account Where Id in :testSet OR Id in :testSet2];
```

But after Spring '17 upgrade on some of our sandboxes we receive a `System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object` on line 4..

This is because one of the parameters is `null`.

Anybody else having this problem or already reported it to SFDC?

** EDIT ** I opened a Case with SFDC and they confirmed they could replicate it as well. Will post any updates here.

** EDIT2 ** Known Issue status just changed to SCHEDULED - SPRING '17 PATCH 7.0

Comment: I've just tested this and I can confirm that this is indeed a problem.

Comment: I would actually expect this behavior and say that when it worked, that was the bug. Granted, there is surely code now that depends on this behavior.

Comment: I agree Adrian, but in that case I'd expect it to be fixed only in the newest API and the rest to remain backwards compatible, as is claimed by SFDC.

Comment: So the new behavior applies to all API versions? That wasn't clear to me  based on your original post.

Comment: I agree with Adrian that this should have been the behaviour and the previous behaviour was actually a bug. We had run into governance limit due to this once. Previously, when a collection(map) was null, it would not error out, instead do a search all and that is why we hit the governance limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related to the known issue:

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gF2QAI

and it should be fixed in a patch release soon.

Comment: Received the response today from SFDC support, pointing to the same KI. Thanks for adding!